# Truncating an array in Javascript by setting length to 0 is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using the `myarray.length = 0` method to truncate an array via a custom `Array.prototype.clear()` method.

This has worked so far to my knowledge, but I now have a particular case where it's setting the `length` to `0`, but the elements still remain.

I've run a basic Array test and it seems to work, but in this more complex case, it is not, so it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Here is the extension code on my `Array.prototype` that I have used...

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'clear', {
    value: function clear() {
        // Clear the array using the length = 0 method. See the method's comments on links to more information and benchmarks on this technique.
        this.length = 0;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: false
});
```

When I call it on all other cases, the following works brilliantly.

```
var myarray = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9, new Date() ];
myarray.clear();
console.log(myarray);   // all cleared.  { length: 0 }
```

But in my more complex case where the array has about 10-20 elements and I call the `.clear()` on the array, it sets the length to `0` but the elements can still be seen if I `console.log` the array like I did above.

```
// e.g. { 0: ..., 1: ..., 2: ..., 3: ..., 4: ..., length: 0 }
```

The only difference is that the `Array` object I am using is an *extended* object, with an override, which *does* call the overridden function. something like so...

```
function Collection() { Array.apply(this); }
Collection.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
    push: {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function(item) { 
            // ...does a type checks on 'item'
            Array.prototype.push.apply(this, [ item ]);
        }
    },
    clear: {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function() { Array.prototype.clear.apply(this); }
    }
});
```

This is happening in Chrome, and I have stepped it thru to the `Array.prototype.clear` method, just as my testing did, but for some reason it does not work in the second case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you're trying it on an object, and on an object `length` would just be another property, and wouldn't change the contents of the object. Note that it's generally a bad idea to extend native prototypes

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad idea to extend natives ... with the exception of `Array` - it has "magic powers" compared to other natives

Comment: @JaromandaX - it's not always a bad idea, but it's *generally* a bad idea, meaning I think it should be avoided, for instance in this case, where a regular `clear(Array)` would do the same thing, without touching the prototype. At least it's not enumerable.

Comment: agreed, @adeneo I misunderstood - I was thinking of his class extension

Comment: Thanks, but ended up changing it to `Array.prototype.splice()` until I find something better.   @adeneo, this project is massive, so trying to keep things object'ified where possible.  Your idea about it being treated as an object; never considered it, as I was calling the Array's prototype function.  But interesting to know.

Answer (score 2):

if you use new ES2015+ `class`

```js
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'clear', {
        value: function clear() {
            this.length = 0;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: false
    });

    class Collection extends Array {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(...args);
        }
        push(...args) {
            console.log('overridden push', ...args);
            // only push even values for example
            super.push(...args.filter(x=>x%2 == 0));
        }
    }

    var x = new Collection();
    x.push(1,2,3,4);
    console.log('after push', JSON.stringify(x));
    x.clear();
    console.log('after clear', JSON.stringify(x));
```

or you can avoid adding clear to array

```js
    class Collection extends Array {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(...args);
        }
        push(...args) {
            console.log('overridden push', ...args);
            // only push even values for example
            super.push(...args.filter(x=>x%2 == 0));
        }
        clear() {
            this.length = 0;
        }
    }

    var x = new Collection();
    x.push(1,2,3,4);
    console.log('after push', JSON.stringify(x));
    x.clear();
    console.log('after clear', JSON.stringify(x));
```

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. I like the ES2015+ and would love to use it...alas browser (backward) support just still isn't fully there yet *sigh*.   I wonder if it has something to do with it being an Object, as @adeneo mentioned.   Have resulted in using the `Array.prototype.splice()` method, which seems to do the trick.